# event triggering multiple times in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, events, dynamic-content

I have a code which is using Vanilla JS. Using a button I added dynamic content. But the problem is when I clicked a dynamically generated content, then it returns
first click: 1
second click: 3
third click: 6
fourth click: 10

but it should be 1, 2, 3, 4

HTML Code Below:

```
<p>Add Content</p>
  <div class="dynamic-content">
```

JS file Below:

```
let counter = 1;
document.querySelector("p").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector(".dynamic-content").innerHTML += `
    <span>My dynamic content - ${counter}</span>
  `;
  counter++;
});

document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", function(){
  let contentList = document.querySelectorAll(".dynamic-content span");
  if(contentList.length){
    contentList.forEach(function(el){
      el.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        console.log(event.target.innerText);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Note: We can't use jQuery

[image: v]

Comment: No wonder, every time you click on the document body, you're adding a bunch of new listeners to the elements.

Comment: It's almost never right to add event listeners inside another event listener.

Comment: When you add a new span, just add an event listener to that span. Don't add the event listener to ALL spans every time.

Comment: Or use event delegation so you don't need to add a new event listener every time.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let counter = 1;
document.querySelector("p").addEventListener("click", function(){
  const element = document.createElement("span") 
  element.innerHTML += `My dynamic content - ${counter}`;
  document.querySelector(".dynamic-content").appendChild(element)
  element.addEventListener("click", function(){
     console.log('element')
     // here logic
  })
  counter++;
});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp
Try with `document.createElement` and then add the event to created element, in this solution you will add only one event to the HTML tag.